# Images in an RSS feed

Tags: customization, images, rss, feed

I'm using Advanded Custom Fields on my WP site to sent text and images to an RSS feed. The RSS feed is used in digital signage software. I have tried to sent more than one image to the feed, using the media-content tag **or** the enclosure tag. But within item tags it's only possible to show one image. And that works well.

Question: is it possible to sent more than 1 image to an RSS feed using custom fields and how?